# How can I receieve the WriteIOPS information for an Elasticsearch cluster through Python?

Tags: python, elasticsearch, boto3

I've been trying to find the WriteIOPS information for Elasticsearch in a format that I can run a small python script to read it.  I have looked into both `boto3` and `elasticsearch` libraries and have found nothing.  Is it potentially a number I have to calculate myself?  Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could request nodes statistics in Elasticsearch by running the following requests (1st is requesting for all nodes, while 2nd just for three nodes with ids)

```
GET /_nodes/stats
GET /_nodes/node1,node2,node3/stats
```

One of the section in those stats is **io-stats** information (unfortunately, only if you’re running Linux):

```
"io_stats" : {
          "devices" : [
           {
              "device_name" : "device-name",
              "operations" : 11014,
              "read_operations" : 5532,
              "write_operations" : 5482,
              "read_kilobytes" : 176740,
              "write_kilobytes" : 685711
            }
          ],
          "total" : {
            "operations" : 11014,
            "read_operations" : 5532,
            "write_operations" : 5482,
            "read_kilobytes" : 176740,
            "write_kilobytes" : 685711
          }
        }
```

Also, JVM section contains **uptime_in_millis** which should help you to get number of operations per second